# Turn Xubuntu into Ubuntu while keeping Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu

Recovering from a terrible attempt to install Ubuntu 13.04, I stumbled upon Xubuntu 13.04. I love it, and so far I have absolutely no complains about it. However, I am not confortable with its default programs. Is there a way I can install all default programs (Nautilus, terminal, Rhythmbox, Open Office, etc) of Ubuntu 13.04 and erase all those of Xubuntu while keeping the environment?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean you want the programs that come with Unity by default, run the following:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Please be aware that this will install the entire GNOME platform, as GNOME applications like Nautilus depend on the GNOME platform. It will also install Unity, but you can remove specific packages if you don't want them.

Also, in case you didn't know, Xubuntu is the same as Ubuntu, except with a different set of programs installed by default (including a different desktop environment).

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question, though.  This would be more akin to running `sudo apt-get install xfce4` and then taking the time to purge all the Unity bits.  **That** would accomplish what the questioner is seeking, perhaps.

Comment: @StephenMichaelKellat in retrospect,  I do agree that it could be more thorough